# Meaning of battle outcomes - i.e Heroic Victory

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

Is there a guide/meaning to outcome of battles in Shogun 2? For instance, close victory, or heroic victory?

Is there a consequence? For instance, stars increase more with heroic than close? Or other benefits/penalties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the various phrases don't seem to have any effect on gameplay. The exception being Heroic Victory which gives your general fifteen experience points instead of the usual ten points. For the most part, they seem to just be aesthetic though.

- **Heroic Victory:** Be outnumbered, but win without many losses. Gives four extra experience points to your leading general.
- **Decisive Victory:** Similar to Heroic, but I don't know whether you need to be outnumbered, and I think you can lose more units than with Heroic.
- **Costly/Close/Pyrrhic Victory:** These seem really weird. It seems to be losing a lot of people and still winning, but the actual conditions seem really hazy.
- **Close Defeat:** Like a Close Victory, but the other way around. (Lose, but without losing many people.
- **Crushing Defeat:** Have the enemy get a Heroic Victory on you. (Have more people but lose without your opponent losing many.)

There may be others, but they don't really matter from what I can tell.

Comment: When I play this more, I'll try to pay closer attention to the battle outcome types.

Comment: thanks. I was trying to figure out what to do more, so general gains more stars. In Rome TW, I was able to to get a 10 star general with a few Heroic victories, along with some other normal ones. So far, it hasn't worked that way, so things most likely have changed.

Comment: @Nasir: Oh, darn. It does...

Answer (score 0):

I heard (and so far my experience confirms it, but I'm far from sure) that decesive victory (or better) wipes out enemy.